Drawing geofence polygon using ThinkGeo MAUI
I am building a custom GIS application in .NET MAUI using ThinkGeo.   My users need to draw a polygon on the map and get notifications when a user enters or leaves the polygon.
I can programmatically create polygons using the InMemoryFeatureLayer, but the users now want to draw the geofences themselves.
Does anyone know what class to use for drawing a polygon or have a sample using ThinkGeo for MAUI?

For a user to draw or edit shapes on a ThinkGeo map, use the TrackOverlay and EditOverlay properties on the MapView.  These will work for the MAUI map as well as WPF and Winform.
You can find more details on this blog post.  If you want to learn more about vehicle and asset tracking, we have another post here that shows a sample implementation.
